# ¿Vincular información con imagen en Firebase?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, recyclerview

Estoy haciendo una app de compras en android studio con java y cada producto tiene información basica como: nombre, descripción, valor, y la foto del producto. Todos los productos se muestran en un recyclerview de donde obtengo el id para la informacion pero no se como obtener la uri de descarga para la imagen.
La información esta guardada en firebase-realtime database y la imagen en firebase-storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es que cuando creas el producto y subes todos sus metadatos a Firebase como nombre, descripcion, etc, tambien debes asegurarte de cargar la imagen en Firebase Storage y obtener una URL de descarga, una vez tengas esa URL de descarga mandas todo el objeto completo con nombre, descripcion, imageURL y lo que necesites a esa referencia en Firebase.

Luego obtienes ese producto con todos sus datos incluyendo la URL de la imagen

Documentacion para subir un archivo y obtener la URL : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?hl=es